# Why does signInWithPopup not work with shadcn/ui's button?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase with Next JS 14 and shadcn/ui. I was making a Sign In page and I used shadcn/ui's button to create three buttons to sign in with Google, Github and Facebook. I added an `onClick` onto each of the buttons to sign in with Google, Github and Facebook respectively. I used the `signInWithPopup` function for all of the functions tied to the `onClick`'s. However, when I click the buttons, nothing happens at all. A window doesn't open or anything and it seems as if `onClick` isn't working. Here is my code for the page:

```
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

import {
  FaGoogle,
  FaGithub,
  FaFacebook
} from "react-icons/fa";

import { app } from "@/lib/firebase";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  GithubAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider
} from "firebase/auth";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const auth = getAuth(app);

  const withGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  const withGithub = () => {
    const provider = new GithubAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  const withFacebook = () => {
    const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="flex justify-center pt-64">
        <Card className="w-96">
          <CardHeader>
            <CardTitle> Sign In </CardTitle>
            <CardDescription>
              Sign in using one of these methods
            </CardDescription>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardContent>
            <div>
              <Button onClick={withGoogle}>
                <FaGoogle className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Google
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className="pt-3">
              <Button onClick={withGithub}>
                <FaGithub className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Github
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className="pt-3">
              <Button onClick={withFacebook}>
                <FaFacebook className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Facebook
              </Button>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

And here's the Button component code.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Slot } from "@radix-ui/react-slot"
import { cva, type VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

const buttonVariants = cva(
  "inline-flex items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50",
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        default: "bg-primary text-primary-foreground hover:bg-primary/90",
        destructive:
          "bg-destructive text-destructive-foreground hover:bg-destructive/90",
        outline:
          "border border-input bg-background hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground",
        secondary:
          "bg-secondary text-secondary-foreground hover:bg-secondary/80",
        ghost: "hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground",
        link: "text-primary underline-offset-4 hover:underline",
      },
      size: {
        default: "h-10 px-4 py-2",
        sm: "h-9 rounded-md px-3",
        lg: "h-11 rounded-md px-8",
        icon: "h-10 w-10",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: "default",
      size: "default",
    },
  }
)

export interface ButtonProps
  extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
  asChild?: boolean
}

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  ({ className, variant, size, asChild = false, ...props }, ref) => {
    const Comp = asChild ? Slot : "button"
    return (
      <Comp
        className={cn(buttonVariants({ variant, size, className }))}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
)
Button.displayName = "Button"

export { Button, buttonVariants }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in your console? What does the code for your `Button` component look like?

Comment: @Phil i sent the button code in pastebin at https://pastebin.com/wbsZYtvh

Comment: @Phil updated it

Comment: You didn't answer my question about any errors in the console. Open your browser's dev-tools and check for any errors in the _Console_ panel. If there are any, please [edit] your question to include the details

Comment: @Phil fixed now. just had to put use client on the top. thanks